# CSS selectors How to get the index of a particular element

Tags: css, xpath

I am trying to use a css selector to select and item but only work for xpath. What would be the equivalent of this xpath to css.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img[@alt='Authorise this row'])[2].click();
```

If I use the css `img[alt='Authorise this row']` I get a lot of results through say firefinder. Is there a way like xpath where you can get a particular index of the result

Comment: Your XPath example is ambiguous, you're missing a closing double quote and two closing parents - it's not obvious what belongs to the expression and what's an array indexer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401146/select-the-xth-element-on-a-page-that-is-a-yth-child-of-its-parent. While it seems to cover a slightly different thing, it actually is the same question. The answer: try `:nth-child(2)`, but it probably won't work for you. You can't use CSS for this. Either use XPath, or select multiple elements via CSS (`findElements()`) and then use just the one element you need.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 supports the :nth-child selector.  For example, the following CSS targets only the second image:

```
img:nth-child(2) {...}
```

The argument to :nth-child can be either an index, keyword(e.g. odd, even), or a formula.  The selector above selects all second image children of their parents.  You could target it a bit more with something like:

```
#container img:nth-child(2)
```

Reference: [:nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Alternately, you could use jQuery to select a set of elements, and then reference one of them by index.  Like so:

```
var secondImage = $('img')[2];
```

Comment: `img:nth-child(2)` does not select "only the second image". It selects all images that are the second children of their parents. It's equivalent to this XPath expression: `//img[2]`.

Comment: @Slanec - yes you are right, but it can still solve the problem by applying it within a context with something like `#container img:nth-child(2)`.  I will add some clarification to my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: (//img[@alt='Authorise this row'])[2]) is the correct code to use sorry